# find repetitive string in a file

Tags: regex, powershell, cmd

I have a text file `Data.txt` of Size in few MBs.
It has repetitive lines like
`VolumeTradingDate=2017-09-05T00:00:00.000 VolumeTotal=73147 LastTradeConditions=0` in `key=value` format.
There are various `key=value`data, for simplicity I am showing very few.
`Values` are changing in lines.

I want to search all occurrences of `VolumeTotal` with its value and print/dump only that part in separate lines. Its `value` can be upto 25 characters.
I tried using `cmd FindStr`

> findstr /C:VolumeTotal= "C:\Work\Data.txt"

But this doesn't give me desired result. It prints entire line.
Could anyone suggest what could be possible script in cmd or powershell to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in PowerShell with a RegEx that uses look ahead and look behind:

```
Get-Content Data.txt | ForEach-Object { 
    $Check = $_ -Match '(?<= VolumeTotal\=)\d*(?= )'
    If ($Check) { $Matches.Values }
}
```

The pattern: `(?<= VolumeTotal\=)\d*(?= )` looks for any number of digits `\d*` between the strings `' VolumeTotal='` and a space character.

The result is sent to the automatic variable `$Matches` so we return the value of this variable if the pattern has been found.